# REBEL: Relation Extraction By End-to-end Language generation

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to run the following pieces of code:

```
from transformers import pipeline

triplet_extractor = pipeline('text2text-generation', model='Babelscape/rebel-large', tokenizer='Babelscape/rebel-large')
# We need to use the tokenizer manually since we need special tokens.
extracted_text = triplet_extractor.tokenizer.batch_decode([triplet_extractor("Punta Cana is a resort town in the municipality of Higuey, in La Altagracia Province, the eastern most province of the Dominican Republic", return_tensors=True, return_text=False)[0]["generated_token_ids"]])
print(extracted_text[0])
# Function to parse the generated text and extract the triplets
def extract_triplets(text):
    triplets = []
    relation, subject, relation, object_ = '', '', '', ''
    text = text.strip()
    current = 'x'
    for token in text.replace("<s>", "").replace("<pad>", "").replace("</s>", "").split():
        if token == "<triplet>":
            current = 't'
            if relation != '':
                triplets.append({'head': subject.strip(), 'type': relation.strip(),'tail': object_.strip()})
                relation = ''
            subject = ''
        elif token == "<subj>":
            current = 's'
            if relation != '':
                triplets.append({'head': subject.strip(), 'type': relation.strip(),'tail': object_.strip()})
            object_ = ''
        elif token == "<obj>":
            current = 'o'
            relation = ''
        else:
            if current == 't':
                subject += ' ' + token
            elif current == 's':
                object_ += ' ' + token
            elif current == 'o':
                relation += ' ' + token
    if subject != '' and relation != '' and object_ != '':
        triplets.append({'head': subject.strip(), 'type': relation.strip(),'tail': object_.strip()})
    return triplets
extracted_triplets = extract_triplets(extracted_text[0])
print(extracted_triplets)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error.

> TypeError: Can't convert {'output_ids': [[0, 50267, 221, 20339, 2615, 102, 1437, 50266, 1587, 7330, 1073, 13249, 493, 16517, 1437, 50265, 2034, 11, 5, 6833, 15752, 10014, 1437, 50266, 18978, 3497, 1437, 50265, 247, 1437, 50267, 19664, 1780, 219, 1437, 50266, 1587, 7330, 1073, 13249, 493, 16517, 1437, 50265, 2034, 11, 5, 6833, 15752, 10014, 1437, 50266, 18978, 3497, 1437, 50265, 247, 1437, 50267, 1587, 7330, 1073, 13249, 493, 16517, 1437, 50266, 18978, 3497, 1437, 50265, 247, 1437, 50267, 18978, 3497, 1437, 50266, 1587, 7330, 1073, 13249, 493, 16517, 1437, 50265, 6308, 6833, 15752, 10014, 2]]} to Sequence

Can anyone provide a solution for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can run the code successfully without an error PF screenshot. Maybe can you check with your transformers version?

I have a colab notebook using transformers model/tokenizers functions directly maybe you can use them directly.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12gwdua-Fs7H31HIc5frzavT6ofyeLWux?usp=sharing

I hope this helps, Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It already worked out, a version of Transformers/tensorflow was required I think. Thanks!